# how do i implement the session to redirect in below codes?

Tags: php, yii

m using the following code as mentioned below but some how if condition  the second of second block fails,
and every time the page gets redirected to the link mentioned in 2nd if block.

```
 if($_session['redirect']=='')
    {
    Yii::app()->session['redirect'] = 'redirect';

    }
    if(Yii::app()->session['redirect']=='redirect')
    {
        Yii::app()->session['redirect'] = 'redirect_test';
        $this->redirect(array('/site/page','view'=>"nh7"));
    }
```

Comment: have mentioned session_start() at the top of my page

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Your code is setup to have it eventually redirect to the link in the second block if the session variable is set to '' or 'redirect'

Comment: actually i want to redirect to the link every time user logs-in and so have set the session variable to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
if(!Yii::app()->user->hasState('redirect'))
    Yii::app()->user->setState('redirect', 'redirect');

if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('redirect')) {
    $redirect = Yii::app()->user->getState('redirect');
    if($redirect == 'redirect') {
        Yii::app()->user->setState('redirect', 'redirect_test');
        $this->redirect(array('/site/page','view'=>"nh7")); 
    }               
}
```

Please use `Yii:app()->user->setState()`, `setState()`, and `getState()` rather than `Yii::app()->session['key']`

Comment: TRIED this the problem is that browser is by defalut setting a cookie,dont knw how and due to which even after i close the browser next tym the session take the value from the cookie.. and i m not redirected to the page.... above codes are used in a facebook application

Comment: so wat i need is when user visit the  application he is directed to this page as redirected... but as cookie get set i dont get redirected to the page even after i quit the application n re-enter it.

Comment: @aslingga: why don't you just use a normal `else` block instead of repeating the whole condition.....??